# How could I analyze multiple instances of a line graph centered on an event to see if they share a common pattern

Tags: time-series, correlation

I have a continuously running metric that may or may not correlate with discrete events. For my example, consider the blue line the continuously recorded metric and the orange line the discrete event. I'd like to see if some change in the continuous value that is recorded before the event leads to the discrete event.

[image]

I'm not a stats person, but I've gotten as far as normalizing the time series around the discrete event (if you compare you can see the blue line in the lower graph is the first instance, the orange line is the second instance, and the grey line is the third instance) such that instead of a single line we have three distinct observations. I would like to see if there is a common pattern to the left of the black vertical bar, but I don't know how I would do that.

[image]

I intuitively assume if I saw all metrics dive at 6 seconds to the event or spike at 3 seconds to the event, that would be a probable cause of the event. That said, there's a big difference between thinking I see a pattern in a graph and it being a statisticallys significant pattern, and I don't know if it's possible to actually verify the above analysis mathematically.

Comment: To answer some inevitable follow-on questions, I actually have multiple different kind of metrics to do the above sort of analysis on, but once for each metric. What I would like to do is determine if any one (or multiple) metrics share some common pattern some common amount of time before the event I want to predict.

Comment: Also, the above isn't real data, just to help show the problem as I understand it.